# Issue with Copied and Pasted Input - Pasted input only taking first value

Tags: python, list, split, unique

I am trying to make a function that takes a copied list in Japanese and only returns the unique words, separated by new lines in Google Docs. The image below is my work so far. I do not know why when I paste my copied Google Docs list, it only returns the first value. Any thoughts?

```py
print('Paste your list: ')

j_list = input().split()

def thinner(japaneselist):

    unique_japanese = []

    for x in japaneselist:
        if x not in unique_japanese:
            unique_japanese.append(x)
    for x in unique_japanese:
        print(x)
    print(len(unique_japanese))

print(j_list)
```

When I try copying and pasting this:

私

彼

かれ

私

彼

It just returns:
['私']

[image: Here is my image from PyCharm]

Comment: `input` reacts the same way to pasting as it would if you had typed that data in yourself. If you type 私 and then Enter, the `input` call will complete, and return "私". It won't wait for the rest of your input. If you need to enter multiple lines of data, you need multiple input calls.

Comment: If you want unrepeated values, you can use a `set` instead of a `list`

Comment: As far as my understanding goes, you should enter all the words in a single line separated by spaces."input.split(' ') will take those words and convert them in a list...

Comment: And also where are you calling the function?